# c++ macro based on context

Tags: c++, macros, access-modifiers

I'm injecting code into C++ classes through macros. Is it there a way to do this depending on the access modifiers' context? Something like

```
#if (we_are_in_public_context)
INJECT_PUBLIC_CODE(params)
#else if (we_are_in_protected_context)
INJECT_PROTECTED_CODE(params)
#else INJECT_PRIVATE_CODE(params)
```

Answer (score 3):

No. macros are strictly text-replace.

They're not aware of context.

Comment: Macros can "call" other macros, so the context is the set of other macro definitions. But, changing the definition of a macro in reusable fashion requires a reusable header file (and a headache).

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own access levels:

```
#define PUBLIC INJECT_PUBLIC_CODE(params) \
        public

#define PRIVATE INJECT_PRIVATE_CODE(params) \
        private
```

and use these in your files:

```
class A
{
   PUBLIC:
      A();
   PRIVATE:
      int x;
};
```

Comment: What does `params` do? And they need to be called as `PUBLIC(param)` and `PRIVATE(param)`; without the parens there is no replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your code last or first in class and force yourself the context:

```
#define INJECT_PUBLIC_CODE(params) \
public: \
   DoSomethingPublic(params);\
private:

#define INJECT_PROTECTED_CODE(params) \
protected: \
   DoSomethingProtected(params);\
private:

INJECT_PRIVATE_CODE(params) \
private: \
   DoSomethingPrivate(params);\
private:
```

Good luck